# Finding matrix $A$ knowing that $A^2 = B$

Tags: matrices

Let $B$ be the $3\times3$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&8&5\\
0&9&5\\
0&0&4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

How can I find a triangular matrix $A$ with positive diagonal entries such that $A^2 = B$ ?

Comment: Hint: Start with $1, 3, 2$ along the diagonal.

Comment: How did you determine that the diagonal of the matrix will be equal to 1 3 2

Comment: Because that's the square roots of the elements on the diagonal of $B$. If you square a triangular matrix, then the elements along the diagonal gets squared by themselves. What happens off the diagonal is slightly more complicated, but now that there are only three off-diagonal elements, try to set up the equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&x&y\\0&3&z\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&8&5\\0&9&5\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}
$$and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir Arthur!

Comment: @Arthur For the sake of moving this question off the unanswered list, would you mind posting your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&x&y\\0&3&z\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&8&5\\0&9&5\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$
and wish to find $x, y, z$. This gives
$$
\cases{4x = 8\\3y  + xz = 5\\5z = 5}
$$
where we immediately get the solutions $x = 2, z = 1$, which again gives $y = 1$. So we have
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&3&1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$